# Fail2ban-Regex test always tells no host in group

Tags: debian, regular-expression, smtp, fail2ban

I'm trying to build a filter myself using regex. This is a line i want to filter for example:

```
Aug 30 11:07:38 *** postfix/smtpd[17969]: connect from vps10685425.123-vps.co.uk[46.32.239.160]
```

An this is my RegEx currently:

```
^%(__prefix_line).*:.*connect from.*\[<HOST>\].*$
^%(__prefix_line)s\w{14}:.*connect from[-._\w]+\[<HOST>\].*$
```

Both lines tell me

```
server.failregex.RegexException: No 'host' group in '/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/smtp-auth.conf'
```

Why does fail2ban fail to recognize the host group in my regex? what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you try running fail2ban-regex in the command line? I did it with your log example and first regex and didn't get the host group error.

Comment: Yes, the message occurs with the `fail2ban-regex` command but I added the mail.log and my config file. Maybe there is a problem with the config file?

Comment: sheeeesh I'm with stupid here... I had a typo in my .conf file..

Comment: hehe good that it's solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, abort mission. I'm the stupid one..

Got a Typo in my parameters... it is actually `smtp_auth.conf` not `smtp-auth.conf`

Sorry! Close this one and burry it deep -.-'

Comment: This actually helped me - the error message by fail2ban-regex does not explicitely say that the filter file does not exist, so I didn't notice at first that I uploaded the filter to the wrong server :-D